# Insert table data into another table in another schema in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

i have 2 DBs

the first one

```
username: name1
password: password1
hostname: pdprf.local
port: 8080
SID: prf
```

the second one

```
username: username2
password: password2
hostname: pdora.local
port: 8080
SID: prd
```

i am selecting data from a table in scehama 1 and i want to insert that data into table in scehma 2 - usually i export the data and insert it but i am looking for 1 line statment to do this - any ideas how to do that in oracle DB ?

Answer (score 1):

If these are different databases, then a **database link** is the answer to your question.

Create a database link in one of those databases, e.g.

```
create database link dbl_prd
  connect to username2
  identified by password2
  using 'prd';
```

Then you'd

```
insert into some_table@dbl_prd (col1, col2, ..., coln)
  select col1, col2, ..., coln
  from some_table;
```